# Why I get Flutter mistake screen(red screen) when using CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-cupertino

This is the problem that I got => **The following assertion was thrown building CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus]):
CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton should only be used in routes that can be popped
'package:flutter/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1333 pos 9: 'currentRoute?.canPop == true'**

I really do not understand this situation because I used previous 2 pages there is no problem but last page made problem.

Here is my related code part:(third page)

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final name = basename(widget.file!.path);
    if(Platform.isIOS){
      return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          leading: CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton(
            color: CupertinoColors.white,
          ),
```

This is he way how to come here:
(first page)

```
CupertinoButton(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
   child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.list_bullet, color: CupertinoColors.white,),
   onPressed: () => {
      Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConsumptionReportsScreen(location: widget.location)))
   }
),
```

(second page)

```
onTap: () async {
   // final file = await PDFApi.loadNetwork(reports[index].pdfUrl);
   const url = 'https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf';
   final file = await PDFApi().loadNetwork(url);
   Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => PdfViewerScreen(file: file)));
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting shows that the page you're currently on can't be popped.

```
Failed assertion: line 1333 pos 9: 'currentRoute?.canPop == true'
```

Are you sure there are pages in the stack that can be popped to?

Comment: It is opening, I cannot show you right now but i can navigate. There is only problem that back button place in navigation bar turns red screen first then it is closing. Although it is closing, firstly red screen is a problem. I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Can you add the code for how you come to this page, it'll be somewhat like `Navigator.push` or something, and also add the code for how you're popping these pages.

Comment: Im going to add right now

Comment: I have added the way, you can see from the question @Advait

Answer (score 0):

first return a material app and in and inside it use CupertionoPageScaffold() as home page , i hope this will help

```
    import 'dart:io';

    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
       State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if(Platform.isIOS){
       return MaterialApp(
        home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
          child: Container(),
        ),
      );
     }else {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(),
      );
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not working

Comment: when you give the answer that time please add output (image or gif file) so user can much better understand

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, I have try other way

```
CupertinoPageScaffold(
  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
    middle: const Text('Sample Code'),
    leading: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('Button Pressed');
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      child: Icon(
        CupertinoIcons.left_chevron,
        color: CupertinoColors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: Container(),
),
```

Result screen-> [image]

Comment: Thank you but when i add onpressed and navigator.pop it gives me mistake

Comment: I have update the code please check

Comment: I tried that before as a CupertinoButton. And i tried yours it is not working

Comment: its working for me

Comment: How you pass to this page? Could you send me it

Comment: you can test my code on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) and pressed the arrow button the page is exit

Comment: You dont understand me. Im trusting you that it is working but in my example it is not working. I want to work that but it is not working on my structure

Comment: Also i can do this in not complex example.